# Making a Compass Application iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to integrate a compass module to my app. I used `CoreLocation` Framework and I added `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to my class. I am initializing my class with this code.

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Then I'm calling the function below but I'm not getting any output.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    let h = newHeading.magneticHeading
    let k = newHeading.trueHeading
    print(h)
    print(k)
    label.text = "\(h)"
}
```

I added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to my Info.plist

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you miss..

```
locationManager.startUpdatingHeading

//Starts the generation of updates that report the user’s current heading.
- startUpdatingHeading

//Starts the generation of updates that report the user’s current location.
- startUpdatingLocation
```